# How to make a div reach the bottom of the page in HTML

Tags: html

I can't get my div to reach the bottom of the page. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#Welcome {
 background-color: pink;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<div id="Welcome">
Welcome!
</div>
</html>
```

I did not work when I put in height: 100%; I also tried min-height: 100%; but neither one works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height: 100%` property makes the element to take 100% height of parent element. The parent element should have height defined, else the height will be adjusted based on its children.

In your case height of `html` and `body` should be set to `100%`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
 }
#Welcome {
 background-color: pink;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<div id="Welcome">
Welcome!
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply change `%` to `vh`,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#Welcome {
 background-color: pink;
    height: 100vh;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="Welcome">
Welcome!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, why your code didnt work was because you have tried height:100% but the parent container still wasnt in full height, making the parent containers too at 100% will make it take up full height.